# How to accelerate Windows XP/Vista/Seven keyboard type speed/delay?

Tags: windows, keyboard, speed

It may seem strange but it's true: I've changed the timings for my keyboard to the quickest possible (delay and repetition speed) it's not fast enough for me. And I'm not joking *at all*.

With Ubuntu/Linux, the delay & repetition speed configurations are incredibly accurate and now I'm typing and using key repetition to the maximum speed I can.

I really can't stand this looong key delays and looong key repetition delays anymore (I very often have to move/scroll down up in very long files, and to test credit cards with '0').

Do you know a way to change precisely the delays (hacking registry or whatever) to get to the point I need?

Please don't leave answers like "go 100% Linux" or "plug two keyboards".

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171326/how-can-i-increase-the-key-repeat-rate-beyond-the-oss-limit/3620627#3620627)?

In summary, point Regedit here:
`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Response]`

Now try lowering **AutoRepeatDelay** and **AutoRepeatRate**. You will likely have to reboot before settings take effect.

Comment: This worked but this introduced a *very* annoying stuff: to be able to accelerate the speed you **must** enable the "disabled people options" (I don't know how to say it in English sorry) = turn on FilterKeys. And this means if you press two keys at the same time one will be ignored! I'm used to press CTRL and SHIFT to select word in gmail, this doesn't work anymore, same for CTRL SHIFT TAB to go to previous tab with Firefox. This is actually so annoying that I went back to the old speed. And I'm longer and longer under linux and I'm doing my best to stay the longest possible there...

Comment: Check this links: http://www.wikihow.com/Customize-Keyboard-Speed-in-Windows, http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/change-keyboard-settings

Comment: @guillegr123: OP already has those settings at maximum and needed *more* speed.

Comment: Sample values was described here http://superuser.com/a/509811/139371 They worked for me.