# Keyboard - Repeat Rate/Repeat Delay values in Win7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

What are the all possible values of Repeat Rate / Repeat Delay offered by Win 7 concerning Keyboard settings.

Comment: Did you check in the control panel under Keyboard settings?  Or are you looking for something more specific?

Comment: For sure I did. But there are no values, expressed only in words (short/long or fast/slow). I need an exact values in miliseconds.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check in the registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Keyboard`.

The `KeyboardSpeed` property determines the rate at which a character repeats when a keyboard key is held down.

This is a value in the range from 0 (approximately 2.5 repetitions per second) through 31 (approximately 30 repetitions per second). The actual repeat rates are hardware-dependent and may vary from a linear scale by as much as 20%.

The `KeyboardDelay` property indicates the *length of time after a key is pressed and held* down before keystroke repeat messages are sent by the operating system.

This value is in the range from 0 (approximately 250 millisecond delay) through 3 (approximately 1 second delay). The actual delay associated with each value may vary depending on the hardware.

[source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.keyboardspeed.aspx)

Comment: This answer does not appear to be supported by the information given in the "source" link.

Comment: The link has been changed since I posted it, it was a direct copy/paste ;(.  This is a likely replacement: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978658.aspx

Answer (score 42):

Leave `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Keyboard` alone and try `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Response]` instead. Try the following settings which activate so-called filter keys:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Response]
"AutoRepeatDelay"="200"
"AutoRepeatRate"="6"
"DelayBeforeAcceptance"="0"
"Flags"="59"
```

Flags has to be `59`, other values are in `ms`. Needs logout or restart to activate. Experiment as you wish, though I found `AutoRepeatDelay` less than `200` generating unneeded repeats. I tested XP Home and Prof, as well as Windows 7 64 bit, and it worked excellently.

Original values, just in case of trouble, are:

```
"AutoRepeatDelay"="1000"
"AutoRepeatRate"="500"
"DelayBeforeAcceptance"="1000"
"Flags"="126"
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I used auto-repeat value of 725 for my 1000 Hz polling rate keyboard, it was doing random repeats and this fixed it :)

Comment: Total hack! But it works!

Comment: What is bounceTime ?

Comment: Excellent trick EXCEPT that it causes controlling keys to stick (I have my Ctrl and Win sticking even in games, completely gone after disabling this trick).

Comment: Worked very very well for my Windows 7 on a ThinkPad T450 previously, now restored the OS partition and  I'm trying again.

Comment: Make sure to enable on Filter Keys or this won't work! (btw this is awesome)

Comment: Use "Flags"="27" to hide Filter Keys icon on the taskbar.

Ref: https://ludditus.com/2016/07/15/microsoft-the-keyboard-repeat-rate-and-sleeping-how-to-work-around-their-idiocy/

Answer (score 2):

For a UI alternative to modifying the registry as described by Appenzeller, this utility lets you tweak to speeds not available through the Control Panel.

https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=41881.0 - FilterKeys Setter... for a faster key repeat (in Windows)

Answer (score 0):

Save this into a `faster_kb.reg` file (extending the top-voted answer for ease of use and set Flags=27 to hide the annoying icons):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Response]
"AutoRepeatDelay"="200"
"AutoRepeatRate"="6"
"DelayBeforeAcceptance"="0"
"Flags"="27"
```