# Increase keyboard repeat rate beyond control panel limits in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

It seems there is already an accepted answer for Windows 7 [here](https://superuser.com/questions/388160/keyboard-repeat-rate-repeat-delay-values-in-win7/509811#509811%22here%22). Has anyone found a way to increase the keyboard repeat rate for Windows 10 beyond the Keyboard Properties control panel?

My settings are maxed out on the keyboard control panel as you can see in the following linked image, yet the repeat rate is far too slow for me.

[image: Keyboard Properties]

I've also tried modifying my registry keys as mentioned in the previous answer, but after logging out and back in, Windows sets the registry entries to all zeros, and enables Filter Keys. The Filter Keys can be turned off, but this doesn't seem to allow for faster-than-allowed repeat speeds.

Comment: Can you tell me how fast it is now?  Weird test "Please type this phrase into the notepad like this" then size the notepad horizontally to fit that ~50 charachters.  Then fire up a seconds hand or stop watch, hold the .a key unshifted for 15 seconds , and tell how many rows you get?  It should not matter much what font or size you use, it did not here.   I get about 11 rows.  Why? because that would be easy, requires no program, and is platform independant.

Comment: Almost 9 rows full of a's, after 15 seconds of holding the a key down at 50 columns wide.  I should mention I am using Windows 10 via Bootcamp on an Mac Book Pro.  I've heard these things can be hardware dependent, but it's strange that Windows 10 does not allow a registry override like Windows 7.

Comment: Ok, so that helps to know , it is not really slow, or having problems, you just want it really fast.

Comment: @Psycogeek, Exactly.  No problems, but I would like to exceed the default key repeat rate available in the Windows Keyboard properties menu.

Comment: I just checked the the above mentioned solution for XP/7/8 and it works for my Windows 10 as well - so your problems might be related to the Mac - Bootcamp - Windows constellation.

Comment: +1 This is where Windows should learn from KDE. Not only do the sliders go far enough, you can actually *enter* whatever crazy values you want… This is not hardware dependent, for sure.

Comment: Also looking for this. I used to have 50/s speeds on my old DOS machine.

Comment: user2394284: I think it may actually *be* hardware dependent. Way back when, PC's relied on the keyboard to do more than you might think, including auto-repeat (typematic) rate. I don't know if Windows still relies on the keyboard for repeats or not. The rate could be set from 2cps to 30cps. The max repeat rate in Windows seems to be 30cps (going by the above test) http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2keyboard/

Comment: @joeking The default values come from the keyboard hardware as the standard keyboard controllers can only be programmed within those margins - they generate repeat presses as programmed - of course the OS is free to disregard those signals from the keyboard and generate keys until the key-release scancode is received, as the X keyboard driver does by default, and Windows does when accessibility settings are enabled

Answer (score 32):

To get around this you could use the "Filter Keys" feature in the Ease of Access center to speed it up. Of course backup your registry before doing this or at least back up the values so you can roll it back if it isn't doing what you want it to do. Go into regedit.exe navigate down to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Response and update your values. Reboot for the changes to be seen.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Response]
"AutoRepeatDelay"="200" 
"AutoRepeatRate"="6" 
"DelayBeforeAcceptance"="0" 
"Flags"="59" 
"BounceTime"="0"
```

Comment: Does repeat rate go faster the higher the number is?

Comment: Repeat rate is faster when AutoRepeatRate is smaller (I guess it is a delay in ms rounded up to the 64Hz interrupt heartbeat of Windows: 15.625ms). And instead of reboot it's enough to sign out + log in

Comment: "AutoRepeatRate"=10 feels better, or maybe 9.

Comment: Great, thank you! Is there any documentation on the other things, like `BounceTIme` and `Flags`?

Comment: Thank you for this! It works for Win 11

Comment: This is highly underrated.