# How do I turn filter keys on and off quicker?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, regedit

I am using the keyboard repeat and pick up rate boost that goes through filter keys here: [Increase keyboard repeat rate beyond control panel limits in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1058474/increase-keyboard-repeat-rate-beyond-control-panel-limits-in-windows-10)

However now I have to use Filter Keys which has an 8 seconds or more wait to turn it on or off holding right shift. Is there a way to make this quicker? Either reduce the wait time on right shift or assign the change to a different key?

It's mostly for gaming where I need to smart cast very quickly and want fast pickup and repeating keys. This can be annoying in instances where I do not want my keys to instantly start repeating. Being able to quickly toggle between the two modes is desirable.