# Increasing keyboard repeat rate beyond control panel limit in Windows 11

Tags: windows, keyboard

I've been trying to increase my keyboard repeat rate when a key is held down beyond the control panel limit in Windows 11. I found [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1223508/1901310) which explains how to edit the registry values with filter keys in order to achieve this. These are my settings:

```
"AutoRepeatDelay"="500"
"AutoRepeatRate"="6"
"DelayBeforeAcceptance"="0" 
"Flags"="27" 
"BounceTime"="0"
```

This does increase the limit, however, it seems to be capped at a rate of 15.625 ms (64 hz). Is there any possible way to increase this further? I'm looking to achieve a 1 ms repeat rate. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a hardware limit, or bios limit.

Comment: This is definitely possible. I know my keyboard supports 1k polling rate though if that is relevant. Do you have a possible source for this?

Comment: polling rate has nothing to do with repeating a character. Polling rate only means, it checks 1000 times a second if a key is pressed or released. It is a USB hardware spec thingy. I have no documentation of this other than that I have a bit of understanding how keyboards went from the old PS/2 to USB etc, and how they evolved, and what they did not evolve.