# windows - How do I disable the keyboard delay?

Tags: windows, keyboard, delay

Is there any way to disable the delay caused when holding a key? I want it to do
`aaaaaaaaaaa` instead of `a    aaaaaaaaa`

EDIT: I want to do this via the command prompt.

Comment: I don't care for the downside. It's for developing a game which requires holding down a key.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - Please don't submit nonsense comments like that.  I was forced to report it for not being constructive.

Answer (score 8):

#### How do I disable the keyboard delay?

As far as I am aware you cannot completely remove the keyboard delay. The shortest delay you can set is "approximately 250 milliseconds".

To set the shortest delay possible:

1. "Start" > "Control Panel" > "Keyboard".
2. In the "Keyboard Properties" dialog select the "Speed" tab.
3. Set the "Repeat delay" to "Short" by dragging the slider to the right hand end.

   [image]
4. Click "OK".

---

#### How can I set this value from a `cmd` shell?

Use the following command:

```
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Keyboard" /v KeyboardDelay /t REG_SZ /d "0" /f
```

The value `"0"` represents the shortest delay possible.

> **KeyboardDelay**
>
> Determines how long after a key is pressed and held down that the character begins to repeat. The values 0 (shortest delay; approximately 250 milliseconds) and 3 (longest delay; approximately 1 second) correspond to the four increments on the Repeat delay scale in Keyboard in Control Panel.

Source [KeyboardDelay](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978658.aspx)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [reg](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) - Read, Set or Delete registry keys and values, save and restore from a .REG file.

Comment: I want to do this via a cmd command. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why do you want to do that via command line?  That wasn't specified as a criteria for an answer within your original question, so you may want to edit it accordingly.  Beyond that, this previous question may help:  [Keyboard - Repeat Rate/Repeat Delay values in Win7](http://superuser.com/q/388160/650163)

Comment: @roydbt Yes. Answer updated.

Comment: @Run5k That answer is incorrect. He has Speed and Delay the wrong way around in the answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill , good catch.  Needless to say, it shouldn't have been flagged as "Accepted" without the OP actually verifying that it worked.

Comment: @roydbt Do you need more help? If this answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to [accept that answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: It doesn't work. It says `The operation completed successfully.` but it doesn't work

Comment: @roydbt Yes it does work. However the command line version doesn't cause the Keyboard Properties dialog to be updated correctly. Using the dialog to set the delay to short changes the registry value to 0. Changing the registry value to 0 does not set the delay to short in the dialog.

Comment: @DavidPostill so how can I make it work in the command prompt?

Comment: @roydbt I just explained it does work when you run the `reg` command from the command prompt. The keyboard repeat delay is set to the minimum value. There is a bug such that the dialog doesn't reflect that value correctly. Just ignore the dialog.

Comment: @DavidPostill but it doesn't work. I have tried it and it's not working.

Comment: @roydbt Well it works for me. I have thoroughly tested it.

Comment: @roydbt Are you running as admin? What is the output from `reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\Keyboard" /v KeyboardDelay`?