# How can I make keyboard cursor move faster?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard, windows-registry, process-hacker

How can I make my keyboard faster? For example if I press arrow keys the cursor moves with a certain speed. I want it at least 2x faster. 
In Control Panel all speed settings are at maximum. I have a gamer keyboard: Raze Black Widows (but not because I am a gamer :)

Comment: "In Control Panel all speed settings are at maximum" It can't go any faster.

Comment: Depending on the application you can also use certain other shortcuts like Ctrl+Arrow to skip whole words.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I doubt. The pooling rate for modern hardware is at least 1000 Hz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved here (totally different question):
[Keyboard - Repeat Rate/Repeat Delay values in Win7](https://superuser.com/questions/388160/keyboard-repeat-rate-repeat-delay-values-in-win7)

Edit [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Response]
to be:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Response]
"AutoRepeatDelay"="150"
"AutoRepeatRate"="15"
"DelayBeforeAcceptance"="0"
"Flags"="59"
```

IT IS A HACK! Not totally happy with it. But it works.

Drawback: a new icon ('Accessibility', looks like a stopwatch) will appear in system tray. Hide it. Never open it. If you open it and you press OK, your current registry values will be overwritten.

Comment: Use "Flags"="27" to hide the new icon from the system tray.

Ref : https://ludditus.com/2016/07/15/microsoft-the-keyboard-repeat-rate-and-sleeping-how-to-work-around-their-idiocy/

Answer (score 0):

1. Go "Control Panel" > "Keyboard Properties" > "Speed" tab > "Character repeat" section
2. There is "Repeat delay" - drag the indicator close to "Short".
3. Hit "Apply" or "OK" (See image below)

(Another solution as mentioned here from @Seth's comment - you can hit **Ctrl+Arrow Right or left**, to scroll faster through words.)

[image]

Comment: I try to avoid down-voting newcomers. So, please read AGAIN my question and update your post to actually answer MY question. Now you only say random stuff.